# Create local Postgresql account

Tags: postgresql

On OS X 10.11.2, I've installed Postgres.app and I'm running the local server. I'm trying to create a local account with a username and password so that I can develop a Rails app locally. However, running the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s {USERNAME}
```

I receive `sudo: unknown user: postgres` error.

Any suggestions as to why this error occurs and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

sudo tells you there is no **system user** "postgres".

When you installed PostgreSQL, it should have created **database user** "postgres" and you can try use that:

```
$ psql -u postgres
postgres=# create user {username} password '{password}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a user with the following steps.

In the terminal:

```
createuser --superuser {USERNAME}
```

I then set a password in psql:

```
\password {USERNAME}
```